# C++: Copy the vector of pointers to arrays, to Eigen::ArrayXd

Tags: c++, eigen

I have `std::vector<double *> x`, in which each elements points to C-style double array. The values of double arrays are changing with each iteration of my program. I would like to create a copy of them into `Eigen::ArrayXd x_old` so I can compute a difference with new values. I have tried to use `Eigen::Map` but it copied only one array and they were still connected memory-wise, so it was not a copy technically. Now I tried to `memcpy` it, but I am getting only the first array. Thank you for your help

```
std::vector<double *> x;
x.push_back( new double[2]{1, 2} );
x.push_back( new double[2]{3, 4} );

Eigen::ArrayXd x_old(4);
memcpy(x_old.data(), *x.data(), 4*sizeof(double));
```

Comment: why do you use `new` and `double*` rather than `std::array<double,2>` or `std::vector<double>` ?

Comment: I am using a library that requires it to have like that. Or at least according to my understanding, I need to pass somehow 2D arrays. `double const* const* parameters`

Comment: ok, thats a reason ;)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you interface with that library? Does the library allocate the vector of `double*` or do you have to allocate it and pass it to the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `memcpy(x_old.data(), *x.data(), 4*sizeof(double));` is that since you manually allocated memory for each elements of the `vector`, the data underneath aren't contiguous anymore, ie `2` is not followed by `3`.(The locations of the pointers are contiguous, but the arrays they are pointing to are not)

So when you put them into `x_old`, you can't get them as a contiguous memory. Instead you need to add each elements of the `vector` separately:

```cpp
memcpy(x_old.data(), x[0], 2 * sizeof(double));
memcpy(x_old.data() + 2, x[1], 2 * sizeof(double));
```

Or write a for-loop:

```cpp
for(std::size_t s = 0; const auto& data: x)
{
    memcpy(x_old.data() + s, data, 2 * sizeof(double));
    s += 2;
}
```

---

Sidenote, `*x.data()` is the same as saying `x[0]`.